# How to create XSSFShape with no border outline of the shape?

Tags: apache-poi

In Apache POI 3.9 for HSSFShape class there is a constant 'HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_NONE' and if I apply it using shape.setLineStyle(HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_NONE) then I can create a shape with no border. But in XSSFShape I guess similar constant 'XSSFShape.LINESTYLE_NONE' or something like that is missing. Please help with some another way by which I can create a XSSFShape with no border outline..

Comment: If you create a shape in Excel with no linestyle, save it as .xlsx, and read it back in POI, what does POI report it as having?

Comment: Please let me know how to read Shape from a XSSFSheet.. I couldn't find any way as because the shapes are not associated with any particular cell so reading cells doesn't help.