# Removing border of XSSFShape in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am using XSSF to draw shapes on a worksheet. Contrary to HSSF, XSSF draws these shapes with a border outline. While this is fine with some of my shapes, I don't want it with some of the other shapes. However, I have not found a way to disable the border outline from Apache POI. [`XSSFShape`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFShape.html#setLineStyle-int-) has the method `setLineWidth(double lineWidth)` but putting any value in here does not change the default border. So far, the only way for me to disable it is in Excel itself.

Any help in how to achieve this in XSSF? Here is the same question asked nearly 4 years ago, but no answer as of yet:

[How to create XSSFShape with no border outline of the shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396330/how-to-create-xssfshape-with-no-border-outline-of-the-shape)

Comment: Wondering why no answer? Well your problem is not reproducible. When I am creating a shape using [XSSFDrawing.createSimpleShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.html#createSimpleShape-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor-) then this shape does not have a border line until I set [XSSFShape.setLineStyleColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFShape.html#setLineStyleColor-int-int-int-) and [XSSFShape.setLineWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFShape.html#setLineWidth-double-).

Comment: Correct. There was a double drawing somewhere that overlapped and drew it with an outline.